# List files in specific subdirectories

Tags: linux, centos

I have a folder structure like this:

```
/1/a/x
/1/b/y
/2/a/z
/2/b/d
/3/a/r
/3/b/e
```

I want to list files + filesize for all files in subfolders in the 'a' folders. I've tried using find but am stuck. What would be the right command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print size and full path, try this.

```
find /[123]/a/* -type f -printf '%s %p\n'
```

See [`man find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) for other format strings you could use with `-printf`. In particular, you might want `%P` or `%f` instead of `%p` and perhaps `%b` instead of `%s`.

`[123]` matches a name which is a single digit in the range 1-3; perhaps extend it to `*` or something a bit more constrained if your example doesn't exactly correspond to the reality you are trying to describe.

GNU `find` should be standard on CentOS but if you need properly portable code, perhaps use `find ... -exec stat {} \;` (but note that `stat` too has portability issues; the command should exist on most platforms but how exactly to get it to print something specific varies between implementations).  Another option is `find ... -ls` but then you are up against [parsing `ls`.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

If you don't need to traverse subdirectories, you don't need `find`.

```
stat -c '%s %n\n' /[123]/a/*/*
```

Comment: You may like to add that if the questioner needs to scan directories named `a` below the first-level subdirectory he will need `find /[123]/ -type f -path '*/a/*' ...`.